# git track binary files but ignore content?

Tags: git

Is there a way in git to track binary files without git caring about the contents? The tracking would mainly be for historical reasons.

If not; is there a way to have git track all files but ignore contents of files over N size?

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "track binary files without caring about the contents". What exactly would you like Git to do with these files?

Comment: May I ask ***why*** you want to do this unusual thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in git to track binary files without git caring about the contents?

Not with native git.

You can check-out **[git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)**, which is pretty close of what you want.

> `git-annex` allows managing files with git, without checking the file contents into git.
>
> While that may seem paradoxical, it is useful when dealing with files larger than git can currently easily handle, whether due to limitations in memory, time, or disk space.